# Story about a mental, emotional, and physical energy absorbing girl, with a romance subplot

Tags: story-identification, novel

The novel in question is about an Asian girl who attracts all types of energy towards her, even emotional. This is not good for her, because when she is filled up, she releases it as a big blast.

There is a woman who sends an agent to rescue/bring that girl to her so that she can teach her to live a life while balancing these energies. The agent and the girl fall in love with each other.

Comment: Any idea about the age of this story?  e.g. how long ago did you read this?

Comment: Do you have any more info from the story?